# AMember Pro - .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amember

I'm currently trying to install AMember and I've uploaded the filed to the FTP, however, I whenever I navigate to the install link:

http://domain.com/amember/setup

I am receiving this error message:

————————————————————————————————————————

"Seems your webhosting does not support mod_rewrite rules required by aMember. There may be several reasons:

You have not uploaded file amember/.htaccess (it might be hidden and invisble with default settings)

Your webhosting has no mod_rewrite module enabled. Contact tech support to get it enabled

Your webhosting uses software different from Apache webserver. It requires to convert rewrite rules located in amember/.htaccess file into the webserver native format. Contact webhosting tech for details.

You may continue aMember installation, but aMember will not work correctly until mod_rewrite issues are resolved."

————————————————————————————————————————

I'm not exactly sure how to work around this.  The host I'm using is Hostmonster, and I've contacted support which directed me to a page regarding mod_rewrites, however, I'm not sure where to go from there.

The page they sent me can be found here: https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/94

Also, in case it's worth noting, here's what the current .htaccess file in the AMember directory has in it.

```
#  Sample Nginx rules configuration:
#  aMember rules (replace /amember to actual aMember Pro path from site root)
#
#       location ~* ^/amember/.*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|csv)$ {}
#       location ~* ^/amember/setup/index.php$ { try_files not-existing-file @php; }
#       location ~* ^/amember/js.php { try_files not-exiting-file @php; }
#       location ~* ^/amember/index.php$ { try_files not-existing-file @php; }
#       location ~* ^/amember/public.php$ { try_files not-existing-file @php; }
#
#       location ~* ^/amember/public { rewrite ^.*$ /amember/public.php; } 
#       location ~* ^/amember/setup { rewrite ^.*$ /amember/setup/index.php; }
#       location ~* ^/amember { rewrite ^.*$ /amember/index.php; }
#
#  you must already have something like that in your nginx configuration:
#
#       location ~ \.php$ {
#          try_files not-existing-file @php;
#       }
#       location @php {
#         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#         include fastcgi_params;
#       }
#
#  it is necessary to have @php section, as it is referred by aMember rules, and 
#  it must be located at bottom
#
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^public public.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^js.php js.php [L]
    RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|csv|html)$ index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
#  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance for any help, Bc.